# Cast from 'X.Type' to unrelated type 'Y.Type' always fails

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a single generic fetch function to pull any entity from Core Data and then convert it to one of my data transfer objects. But I'm stuck on how to cast from my protocol `DTO` to a specific implementation of a `DTO`.

```
public func getEntity<T: DTOConvertible, Y: DTO>(CDtype: T.Type, id: CVarArg, DTOType: Y.Type) -> Y.Type {
    let request = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    request.predicate = predicate
    
    guard let entityCD = try? moc.fetch(request).first else { return Y.GetDefaultInstance() as! Y.Type }
    
    return entityCD.ToDTO() as! Y.Type //error here
}
```

I've added the `DTOConvertible` protocol to my Core Data classes to add the `ToDTO()` converter function.

```
protocol DTOConvertible: NSManagedObject {
    func ToDTO() -> any DTO
}

extension ExerciseCD : Identifiable, DTOConvertible {
    public func ToDTO() -> DTO {
        return Exercise(ExerciseId: self.exerciseId, ExerciseName: self.exerciseName)
    }
}
```

All my DTO structs conform to the `DTO` protocol.

```
public protocol DTO {
    static func GetDefaultInstance() -> Self
}

public struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable, DTO {
    public var id: String { return ExerciseId }
    public var ExerciseId: String
    public var ExerciseName: String
    
    public static func GetDefaultInstance() -> Exercise {
        return Exercise(ExerciseId: "", ExerciseName: "")
    }
}
```

If I change the implementation of `ToDTO()` on `ExerciseCD` to return `Exercise` (the specific DTO), then the compiler complains that `ExerciseCD` doesn't conform to the `DTOConvertible` protocol. But I also can't cast from `DTO` to `Exercise` even though `Exercise` conforms to `DTO`. Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Y` You can use `T.SomeTypeAlias`.

```
protocol DTOConvertible: NSManagedObject {
    associatedtype D: DTO
    func toDTO() -> D
}
```

Then in `getEntity`

```
public func getEntity<T: DTOConvertible>(CDtype: T.Type, id: CVarArg) -> T.D { //Simplify this line
    let request = T.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<T>
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
    request.predicate = predicate
    
    guard let entityCD = try? moc.fetch(request).first else {
        return T.D.getDefaultInstance() //Use T.D to access default
    }
    
    return entityCD.toDTO() //Convert
}
```

Then the entity only needs a minor change

```
extension ExerciseCD : Identifiable, DTOConvertible {
    func toDTO() -> Exercise  { //Should start with lowercase and return type.
        return Exercise(exerciseId: self.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString, exerciseName: self.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString)
    }
}

public protocol DTO {
    static func getDefaultInstance() -> Self //Should start with lowercase
}

public struct Exercise: Codable, Identifiable, DTO {
    public var id: String { return exerciseId }
    public var exerciseId: String //Swift convention variables should start with lowercase
    public var exerciseName: String //Swift convention variables should start with lowercase
    
    public static func getDefaultInstance() -> Exercise { //Swift convention methods/functions should start with lowercase
        return Exercise(exerciseId: "", exerciseName: "")
    }
}
```